# How to use DOM referenced .value's in different scopes? (refactoring/scope issue)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scope, refactoring

Thanks for stopping by! I have a piece of working code [here at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s72jv4wk/5/)

It's a basic sort of a calculator that takes 4 values, runs them through a function and spits out the result. It works as expected until I try to refactor the code. As soon as I try to refactor it at least like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s72jv4wk/6/), which gives me NaN or 0 whatever I do.

Here's the original code itself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
```

## See how rich you can get just flipping stuff

```
<input type="number" id="bp" placeholder="Buying price">
<input type="number" id="n" placeholder="Amount">
<input type="number" id="sp" placeholder="Selling price">
<input type="number" id="t" placeholder="Tax % (1 by def, 3 prem)">
<button id="button" onclick="profit()">Get rich!</button>
<input type="text" id="r" placeholder="Profit (unless ganked)">
<button id="button" onclick="resetOnClick()">More!</button><br>


<p>Thank HumbleOldMan later, go get rich now.</p>
```

```
var profit = function(){    

  var bp = document.getElementById("bp").value;
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  var sp = document.getElementById("sp").value;
  var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var result = Math.floor((sp*n-(sp*n/100)*t)-bp*n)
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById("r").value = result;
}

var resetOnClick = function(){
  document.getElementById("t").value =
  document.getElementById("sp").value =
  document.getElementById("n").value =
  document.getElementById("bp").value = "";
  console.log("reset clicked");
}
```

// just couldn't use assigned variables for DOM references for a reason. Must be scope bs or I'm just a noob//

And here is what I tried doing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bp = Number(document.getElementById("bp").value);
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("n").value);
    var sp = Number(document.getElementById("sp").value);
    var t = Number(document.getElementById("t").value);
    var r = Number(document.getElementById("r").value);
    var result; 

    var calcProfit = function(bp,n,sp,t,r){ 
        var result = Math.floor((sp*n-(sp*n/100)*t)-bp*n)
        console.log(Number(result));
        r = Number(result);
    }

    var resetOnClick = function(){
      document.getElementById("t").value =
      document.getElementById("sp").value =
      document.getElementById("n").value =
      document.getElementById("bp").value = "";
      console.log("reset clicked");
    } 
  </script>
```

The question is common. What am I doing wrong? I definitely don't wont to settle for the fist version and get used to doing things just like that. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could we please have your HTML code?

Comment: Right, added it all

Comment: You're getting field values on page load, not on click.

Comment: True. That's what I've been missing, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to get the value of input fields while after click, not on page load which will give value to NaN because initially all are empty. Get inside the `calcProfit` function so you'll get updated values.